# sort for a set range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort a range which was set before, but it didn't work, and I'm not able to find what's exactly the problem. So, any help is welcomed

My procedure sort all data in an specific worksheet and then, it's set a range according to a condition.

```
Sub References_Sort()

    ' Activate Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja2")
    ws.Activate

    'Set variables
    Dim LastColumn, LastRow, FirstRow As Integer
    Dim rngCom As Range
    Dim i As Long
   
   'Sort the rows based on the data in column E
    ws.Columns("A:I").Sort _
        key1:=Range("E2"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
        
    'Find which is the last row and last column with data
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    With ws
        'Find first row with value=5 in column E
        FirstRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=5, After:=.Range("E1")).Row
        ' Set range which includes data with value=5 in column E
        Set rngCom = .Range(Cells(FirstRow, "A"), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
          
        'Sort set range based on the data in column B
        rngCom.Sort _
            key1:=Range("B2"), _
            order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
            
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which part "does not work"? Do you get an error? Did you try stepping thru it to watch what it does while it's doing it?

Comment: Hi @braX. It doesn't appear any error when the code is executed. It seems it works perfectly, however it doesn't sort the data contain in ```rngCom``` . So, it seems everything works as it expected except this part of the code: 
```
       'Sort set range based on the data in column B
        rngCom.Sort _
            key1:=Range("B2"), _
            order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: While the code is running, does `Range("B2")` evaluate to the value you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your `Range` objects are not qualified.

Qualify them like this (see comments):

```
Sub References_Sort()

    ' Activate Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja2")
    ws.Activate

    'Set variables
    ' Dimmed them as Long instead of 2 variants and 1 integer
    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim rngCom As Range
    Dim i As Long
   
   'Sort the rows based on the data in column E
   ' (added ws. to the range object)
    ws.Columns("A:I").Sort _
        key1:=ws.Range("E2"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
        
    'Find which is the last row and last column with data
    ' these cells references should probably be qualified too 
    ' added ws. to them
    LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    With ws
        'Find first row with value=5 in column E
        FirstRow = .Range("E:E").Find(What:=5, After:=.Range("E1")).Row
        ' Set range which includes data with value=5 in column E
        ' fixed missing qualifications here too
        Set rngCom = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
          
        'Sort set range based on the data in column B
        ' (added a . to the Range object to qualify it using the with)
        rngCom.Sort _
            key1:=.Range("B2"), _
            order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
            
    End With

End Sub
```

Just for the record, the OP wanted this changed (see comments):

```
rngCom.Sort _
key1:=.Range("B1"), _ 
order1:=xlAscending, _ 
Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: I tried your code added a "." to the Range object to qualify it, but then there is a compilation error.

Comment: In the last sort, the data in ```rngCom``` should be sorted according to column B values, maybe that could be the problem.

Comment: Only you are going to be able to know what you expect, so yes, double check each piece to see if they are all what you expect. Each range/cell reference needs to be qualified.

Comment: Thank you @braX for your help. Now it works :) I qualified all ranges/cells as you recommended me and then, I modified some lines in the sort method ``` rngCom.Sort _
            key1:=.Range("B1"), _
            order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlNo```.